# Taking whole message string as an argument

Tags: c#, string, arguments, discord, discord.net

I want my bot to take the whole message after the command as a whole argument. But right now this is the situation :
 When I type "!math 1 + 3" it only takes "1" as an argument. I want the bot to takes the whole string of "1 + 3" as an argument instead.

This is my code :

```
    [Command("math")]
            public async Task Calculate(string equation)
            {
                string result = new DataTable().Compute(equation, null).ToString();
//Basically to calculate from the string to find the result
                if (result == "NaN")
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Infinity or undefined");
                }
                else
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result);
                }
            }
```

I am currently using Discord.NET v1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Claudiu said, you can enclose the arguments in quotes, or...

Use the [Remainder] attribute like so,

```
[Command("math")]
public async Task Calculate([Remainder]string equation)
{
    // Now equation will be everything after !math
    // Your code here
}
```

P.S.: Ask future Discord.Net questions in our [Discord Server](http://discord.gg/discord-api) (look for #dotnet_discord-net), you'll get your answer much quicker.

Comment: It would probably be wise to explain _why_ this works; the RemainderAttribute signals that the parameter should not stop reading at the next space, but rather read to the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you should enclose in quotes arguments that contain spaces. For example:

application.exe "some argument that contains spaces"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else not using Discord.NET

```
public async Task Calc(CommandContext ctx, [RemainingText] string equation)
```