# Discord bot C# coding. Too few/too many parameters

Tags: c#, discord, bots

I am trying to build a discord bot that fetches IMDb info for movies and series. I have the API and everything set up.

I have managed to get a console response when I use the command !SearchMovie Harry Potter, however it gives me the 'too few parameters' argument if i do !SearchMovie Jaws, or !SearchMovie Twilight. If i remove the (string content) from public async Task SearchMovie, then i get the 'too many parameters' error.

I would also like the bot to post the response body in the discord channel, however i get the 'Message content is too long. Must be equal to or less than 2000 (parameter content)' error. Please, if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, please help.
This is my code:

```
[Command("SearchMovie")]
public async Task SearchMovie(string text, string content)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/auto-complete?q=%3CREQUIRED%3E"),
        Headers =
        {
            { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "API-KEY" },
            { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com" },
        },
    };
    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
        await ReplyAsync(body);
    }
```

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the library you use, which you haven't mentioned or tagged

Comment: Its in C#. I'm using Imdb and RapidApi. I'm having trouble with the string parameters and I have no idea how to code it to get the bot to show responses in the discord channel.

Comment: The term "Harry Potter" is interpreted as "Harry" and "Potter". If you want you could just have a 'string text' parameter with [Remainder] as it's attribute. According to this answer, that attribute will take every bit of text after your command into a single variable: answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053824/taking-whole-message-string-as-an-argument

Comment: Regarding the 2000 character limit, I believe that's just a general text limit all messages have on discord. Have a look at scraping the content you want our of the response body and then posting that back via the ReplyAsynx(). I would suggest making a Class Library that makes these WebRequests, translates the responses into data structures and returns those. That way it'll be much easier to take the data structure and format the message reply.